# Move iTunes library from Windows to Os X

Tags: windows, macos, itunes, migration, libraries

Is there an easy way to move my iTunes library to another computer, including all the songs I obtained from sources other than the iTunes store? I don't need to keep it on the old computer. It is my understanding that the iTunes sync feature in 9 doesn't include non-iTunes songs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Christopher explained, you should just move the entire iTunes directory.  Importantly though there will be an XML file inside your iTunes folder named "iTunes Library.xml".  This file contains references to every item stored inside your iTunes library.

Make a copy of that XML file before messing about.

Open the XML file in a text editor you're comfortable with.  Near the top of the file (was the 9th line for me).  You will see a line similar to this: `<key>Music Folder</key><string>file://localhost/Users/kyle/Shares/Music/iTunes/</string>`

You'll want to replace the values inside of  with file://new/location/of/your/itunes/directory.

I'd suggest doing a find and replace on the entire file.

Open iTunes, it may take a minute but everything should work.

Comment: Looks quite easy to change the directory's in the XML library file, thanks for the tip! +1

Comment: Also, there's no need to copy the *.itl file

Comment: Managed to move my music over. I strongly recommend having the same version of iTunes installed on both computers before you start, as some versions (such as iTunes 9) change the directory structure

Answer (score 1):

Locate the following folder

XP

> C:\Documents and Settings\Username\My
>   Documents\My Music\iTunes\iTunes Music

Vista/Win7

> C:\Users\Username\Documents\Music\iTunes\iTunes Music

Copy the following folders contents to (On Mac OS X)

> ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music

where the tilde "~" represents your home directory.

I'm not sure whether the library file is cross-compatible that's why in this suggestion i recommend just copying the Music folder.

Have a read over here

[Mac OS X](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1449)

[Windows XP](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1364)

Comment: Just a note: if the library isn't in that location, look at Preferences -> Advanced to see where it is